# Problema control Accordion de AjaxControlToolkit: No puedo desplegar a la vez todos los paneles

Tags: ajax, asp.net, vb.net

Sobre una página .aspx tengo el siguiente código donde agrego un control Accordion de AjaxControlToolkit:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" CssClass="clear porciento-98 center">
        <div class="TD_TITULO_PANEL">
            <span class="LBL_TITULO_PANEL">Preguntas y Respuestas</span>
        </div>
        <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="accPR" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
                Height="100%"  Width="100%" Event="" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected">
        </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
    </asp:Panel>
```

La parte donde agrego los paneles y contenidos se hace dinámicamente desde servidor desde el evento Load de la página:

...

```
    Load_AccordionPanel()
    accPR.RequireOpenedPane = False
    accPR.SuppressHeaderPostbacks = True
    ExpandAllPanels()
```

...

```
Private Sub Load_AccordionPanel()
    Dim dtFAQs As New DataTable()
    dtFAQs = getFAQByIds(ID, subID)

    Dim i As Integer = 1

    For Each dr As DataRow In dtFAQs.Rows
        Dim lblTitulo = New Label()
        Dim lblContenido = New Label()
        lblTitulo.Text = String.Format("{0}.- {1}", i.ToString, dr("PREGUNTA").ToString())
        lblContenido.Text = dr("RESPUESTA").ToString()
        Dim pn = New AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane()
        pn.ID = "Pane" & i.ToString()
        pn.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(lblTitulo)
        pn.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(lblContenido)
        accPR.Panes.Add(pn)
        Interlocked.Increment(i)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ExpandAllPanels()
    For Each pane As AccordionPane In accPR.Panes
        pane.Style.Add("Display", "Block")
        pane.HeaderContainer.Attributes("class") = "ajax__accordion_header ajax__accordion_headerSelected"
    Next
End Sub
```

Mi intención es que al abrir la página todos los paneles aparezcan desplegados pero no funciona, ni siquiera el poder abrirlos uno a uno de forma manual cosa que permitiría el atributo .RequireOpenedPane = False